# In Servlet Post method did not call from html page?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

i have problem how to call post method in java.When i pressed click button on login page after that did not show any thing on the browser.please tell me proper solution.my output show on console.so please tell me what is mistake.thanks in advance.

> login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/loginPage.css" />

<!-- <script src="js/jquery-ui.1.10.4.js"></script> -->

<title>Login Page</title>
</head>

<section class="login">
    <div class="titulo">Staff Login</div>
    <form action="/AdminLogin" name="AdminLogin" method="post">
        <input type="text" title="Username required" placeholder="Username" data-icon="U">
        <input type="password" title="Password required" placeholder="Password" data-icon="x">
        <div class="olvido">
            <div class="col"><a href="#" title="Ver Carásteres">Register Student</a></div>
            <div class="col"><a href="#" title="Recuperar Password">Fotgot Password?</a></div>
        </div>
       <button class="enviar">submit</button>
    </form>
</section>

</html>
```

> AdminLogin.java

```
package com.admin.main;
import java.beans.Statement;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.admin.dao.UserMasterConnection;

@WebServlet("/AdminLogin")
public class AdminLogin extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Statement stmt;

    UserMasterConnection userMasterConnection = new UserMasterConnection();

    public AdminLogin()
    {
        super();

    }

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {


    }

    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("doget");
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        System.out.println("doPost()");
        /*System.out.println("dopost");
        // connection with database
        // Connection connection =
        Connection connection = userMasterConnection.getConnection();

        String selectTableSQL = "select * from user_detail where username=? and password=?";

        try {
                stmt = connection.createStatement();

                // execute select SQL stetement
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(selectTableSQL);

                while (rs.next())
                {
                    // get username and password from login page
                    String username = request.getParameter("password");
                    String password = request.getParameter("username");
                    System.out.println(username);
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) 
            {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            }*/
        String username = request.getParameter("Password");
        String password = request.getParameter("Username");

        System.out.println("username :-"+username);
        System.out.println("password"+password);


    }

}
```

> web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>SBTsystemAdminView</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>loginPage</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.Admin.main.AdminLogin</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>loginPage</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/loginPage/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: can you show your web.xml file ?

Comment: Try adding name attribute in your input tag

Comment: Try sending a response and check if you see it in the browser:
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println("TEST");

Comment: Where do you have the code that actually ouputs anything to the browser. All I see are System.out calls and that will not print anything to the browser.

Comment: output did not show on the console.

Comment: Did you get empty username and password or no output at all? What was the HTTP response code?

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the empty `service` method override.  Its making the servlet do absolutely nothing.  Read the [documentation for HTTPServlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html) concerning the service method:

> protected void service(HttpServletRequest req,
>                          HttpServletResponse resp)
>                   throws ServletException,
>                          java.io.IOException
>
> **Receives standard HTTP requests from the public service method and dispatches them 
>   to the doXXX methods** defined in this class. This method is an HTTP-specific version
>   of the Servlet.service(javax.servlet.ServletRequest,
>   javax.servlet.ServletResponse) method. **There's no need to override
>   this method.**

In other words, the standard implementation of this method figures out whether the request is GET or POST and routes to the doGet or doPost functions.  If you override this method, especially with a blank function, then you are preventing the doGet and doPost functions from ever being reached.